# ExceptionInInitializerError with getProperty() method in Guava ImmutableMap

Tags: java, initialization, guava, immutability

I have the following utility class:

```
public final class EnvironmentUriAndAuth {

  public static final String ENVIRONMENT = getProperty("environment_type");

  private static final ImmutableMap<EnvironmentConstants, String> AUTH_HEADER =
      ImmutableMap.of(
          DEV, getProperty("devTestAuth"),
          TEST, getProperty("devTestAuth"),
          PRELIVE, getProperty("preliveAuth"));

  // private constructor

  public static String getAuthHeader() {
    return AUTH_HEADER.get(EnvironmentConstants.valueOf(ENVIRONMENT));
  }
}
```

I'm calling method `getAuthHeader()` in another class that should return the value of the property, depending on the value which is written in `environment_type` property.

When I'm calling the `getAuthHeader()` method, I get the `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` on the line that initializes the ImmutableMap.

I guess the issue is with the order of initialization of the `getProperty()` method but can't find the right order.

Is the error caused by the initialization error or something else?

Comment: Do you receive an exception message (if yes, please add it to your question)? These kinds of exception occur when an initialization of a `static` property, in your case `AUTH_HEADER` fails (My bet is that `ImmutableMap` doesn't allow `null` values, and some of your `getProperty()` calls is returning `null`)

Comment: Oh, indeed, it's because of `null`. I didn't pass a value into `preliveAuth` property and thus it's `null`. Thus, the message was: _Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: PRELIVE=null_. Now I passed a value to `preliveAuth` property and it works fine.